# C# Arrays: Index was outside the bounds of the array error

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to generate 5 sets of coordinates (just two integers together in an array) but i get the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array error". Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
    private void BtnAGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int TotalCoordinates = 0;

        int[,] GenaratedCoordinates = new int[4, 1];
        while (TotalCoordinates <5)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int RandomNumberX = rnd.Next(1, 5); // creates a number between 1 and 5
            int RandomNumberY = rnd.Next(1, 10); // creates a number between 1 and 10

            GenaratedCoordinates[TotalCoordinates, 0] = RandomNumberX;
            GenaratedCoordinates[TotalCoordinates, 1] = RandomNumberY;
            TotalCoordinates++;              
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is only one item for the second index, at index 0, yet you are accessing index 1.

Comment: And only 4 items in the first slot (0-3 indexes), yet you will access slot 4

Comment: `int[,] GenaratedCoordinates = new int[5, 2]`.  VB has the other functionality, where array lengths start at zero, thus `int(4,1)` in vb would actually have length of 5 in the first slot and 2 in the second.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array, or multi-dimension array, the value given is the number of elements. However, the indexes start at 0, so if you have `new int[3]`, the possible indexes are `0`, `1`, and `2` (`0` through `n-1` for the general case `new int[ n ]`). So when you use:

```
int[,] GenaratedCoordinates = new int[4, 1];
```

the available indexes are

```
GenaratedCoordinates[0, 0]
GenaratedCoordinates[1, 0]
GenaratedCoordinates[2, 0]
GenaratedCoordinates[3, 0]
```

However you access `GeneralCoordinates[0,1]`, for example, which is invalid and will throw the Exception you are seeing.  It seems like you want an array representing 5 points, so you would need:

```
int[,] GenaratedCoordinates = new int[5, 2]; // 5 points with an x and y coordinate each
```

Or even better, express what you want more clearly by using abstractions that are already available or that you create yourself. In this scenario, there is already a [`System.Drawing.Point struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be used to represent a point. So you can have an array of these structures instead of cryptic multi-dimension array when the second index has the meaning where 0 represents x and 1 represents y:

```
System.Drawing.Point[] GeneratedCoordinates = new System.Drawing.Point[5];
```

and then access them using, for example:

```
GeneratedCoordinates[ TotalCoordinates ].X = RandomNumberX;
GeneratedCoordinates[ TotalCoordinates ].Y = RandomNumberY;
```